# How to ensure that ffmpeg libraries uses/ not uses GPU

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, video, gpu

My library ( Linux,  Debian) uses FFMpeg libraries ( avformat, avcodec, swscale etc) for reading video stream from network cameras. Actually, I need to capture each video frame from network camera, decode it, scale and store in memory- and other thread pass this data to calling program for display.

**Problem is, that all works  in CPU and take a huge amount of CPU resource. How can I enforce usage of GPU accelerator for processing?**

I have video card: *VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 620 (rev 02)*

My decode thread look like this ( I omit declarations, error handling etc, so pls don't look for grammar mistakes:)))

```
fmt = avformat_alloc_context(); 
//initialising, setting option by av_dict_set
// finding video stream index
***
 // finding decoder and allocate its contexts

    frame = av_frame_alloc();

    while ( av_read_frame(ctx->fmt, &pkt) >= 0) 
    {
        AVPacket orig_pkt = pkt;

         avcodec_send_packet(ctx->dec_ctx, pkt);
         avcodec_receive_frame(ctx->dec_ctx, frame);
            *** 
// get buffer allocated for store of frame data
             buff = get_free_buffer(ctx);
        sws_scale(ctx->sws, (const uint8_t * const*)frame->data, 
        frame->linesize, 0, ctx->dec_ctx->height, buff->data,
        buff->linesize);
            ret = decode_packet(ctx, frame, &pkt, &got_frame);
            if (ret < 0)
                break;
            pkt.data += ret;
            pkt.size -= ret;
        }
        while (pkt.size > 0);

        av_packet_unref(&orig_pkt);
    }
*****
```

Comment: This question is not suitable for Super User. It will be migrated soon. To make sure it won’t be rejected, you need to improve it: Provide code that compiles, provide as much of it as possible.

Comment: If you have a hardware decoder available, you need to assign that. Intel CPUs will have QSV or VAAPI accels available. If you want to scale via GPU, you will need to use libavfilter and a corresponding GPU filter e.g. scale_vaapi or scale_qsv

Comment: Gyan thanks. May be this is the solution. Can you pls give me link for suitable example?

Answer (score 0):

You can find HW accelerated ffmpeg recoding commands on the internet, i am using

`ffmpeg -vaapi_device /dev/dri/renderD128 -i "inputfile" -vf format=nv12,hwupload -c:v h264_vaapi -f mp4 -qp 18 -map 0 "outputfile.mp4"`

You can list HW accelerators by command `ffmpeg -hwaccels` and [DRI framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_Rendering_Infrastructure) path using command `ls /dev/dri/`, then video codec/encoder (h264_vaapi in above example) you can find using command `ffmpeg -encoders`. `-f mp4` parameter may not be necessary to define file format, `-qp` sets quality (in this case similar to original), `-map 0` will try to use all streams of the input file, not just the stream with highest quality, first/default subtitle...

On another hand, when i do not define the HW accelerator device and use default encoder libx264, i can see CPU is maxed out and so no HW acceleration is likely used.

Comment: Thanks, but i'm not use ffmpeg commands, I use C program ( .so library) that obtain each frame and  create image for callback display procedure. ( my system is C# code that I run in linux by Mono, and I need to display ( and record) stream from network camera. Gyan's comment, I hope, will be heplpful.